# Reference sites or books to solve good , hard math problems

Tags: reference-works

What are the books and sites that can be used to solve maths problems (hard ones or easy) . I want to learn different methods to solve a problem . Innovative one. So please help. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try the site artofproblemsolving. Also if you are programmatically inclined the site Project euler. Actually in the latter you can formulate questions based on the given problem which typically ask you to write a program to list numbers with certain properties. You can take them up as a theoretical question and count.

Comment: I must second this. AOPS has some really neat problems from past contests and new ones are being posed all over. The books also serve their purpose.

Comment: @Sean Robertson: Thanks. You can also show your appreciation of an answer by upvoting!

Comment: @Sathasivam: Please avoid asking  questions addressed to individuals in public, especially questions not related to the objective of this site. There is a chat option I am told  which  I have never used.